# $\lim A_k x = Ax \implies \lim A_k = A$ for every norm in $\mathbb{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, linear-transformations

> Let $A_k$ be a sequence of linear aplications $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.
>
> Suppose that for all $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ exists $\displaystyle Ax = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}  A_k x$.
>
> Show that A is a linear aplication and $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} A_k = A$ for every norm in $\mathbb{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$

$\mathbb{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ is the set of all linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$A(x+y) = \lim_k A_k(x+y) =\lim_k A_kx+A_ky =\lim_k A_kx+\lim_kA_ky = Ax+Ay$.

$A(\alpha x) = \lim_k A_k(\alpha x) = \lim_k \alpha A_kx = \alpha \cdot \lim_k A_k x = \alpha \cdot Ax$.

$\therefore A$ is linear.

Let $\epsilon>0, \quad \exists  N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|Ax-A_kx|<\epsilon\cdot |x| \; \forall k>N_0$

$\implies |Ax-A_kx| = |(A-A_k)x| = |A-A_k||x|<\epsilon\cdot |x| \implies |A-A_k|<\epsilon$.

I only used the property that $|\alpha A| = |\alpha||A|$ from the norm, which would mean it is valid for every norm. My problem is, $(A-A_k)x \in \mathbb{R^m}$ but $(A-A_k) \in \mathbb{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ so first I have a norm for $\mathbb{R}^m$ and then it changes.

That makes me think I probably cannot affirm that $|(A-A_k)x| = |A-A_k||x|$. Given that, how can I show that $\lim A_k = A$ for any norm chosen?

Comment: All norms are equivalent in ${\rm Lin}(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^m) \cong \Bbb R^{nm}$, so you can assume that the norm is given by the supremum on the unit sphere.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that you can assume $|x|=1$ without losing generality. Then, you can use the inequality

$$|(A-A_k)x| \leq \lVert A - A_k \rVert |x|$$

where $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is the induced (subordinate) norm over the norm $|\cdot|$. Since induced norm attains a maximum for finite dimensional spaces (see [How can we replace $\sup$ with $\max$ in definition of subordinate norm for finite-dimensional vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671311/how-can-we-replace-sup-with-max-in-definition-of-subordinate-norm-for-fini)) there exists a $\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$|(A-A_k) \bar{x}| = \lVert A - A_k \rVert |\bar{x}| = \lVert A - A_k \rVert$$

which means $\lVert A - A_k \rVert < \epsilon$ since $\lim_{k \to \infty} A_k x = A x$ *for all* $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Also, since all the vector norms are equivalent, your proof is completed.